# Iterating over arma::mat and retrieving element locations

Tags: c++, c++17, armadillo

I'm trying to set the values of an `arma::mat` element-wise and the value of each element depends on the multi-index (row, column) of each element.
**Is there a way to retrieve the current location of an element during iteration?**

Basically, I'd like to be able to do something [like in the sparse matrix iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28982320/1827608), where `it.col()` and `it.row()` allow to retrieve the current element's location.
For illustration, the example given in the [`arma::sp_mat` iterator documentation](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#iterators_spmat)) is:

```cpp
sp_mat X = sprandu<sp_mat>(1000, 2000, 0.1);

sp_mat::const_iterator it     = X.begin();
sp_mat::const_iterator it_end = X.end();

for (; it != it_end; ++it) {
  cout << "val: " << (*it)    << endl;
  cout << "row: " << it.row() << endl;  // only available for arma::sp_mat, not arma::mat
  cout << "col: " << it.col() << endl;  // only available for arma::sp_mat, not arma::mat
}
```

Of course there are a number of workarounds to get element locations for `arma::mat` iteration, the most straight-forward ones perhaps being:

- Use nested `for`-loops over the row and column sizes.
- Use a single `for` loop and, using the matrix size, transform the iteration number to a row and column index.
- Some form of "zipped" iteration with an object containing or computing the corresponding indices.

*However,* these seem rather hacky and error-prone to me, because they require to work with the matrix sizes or even do manual index juggling.
**I'm looking for a cleaner (and perhaps internally optimised) solution.** It feels to me like there *should* be a way to achieve this ...

Apart from the solution used for `arma::sp_mat`, other such "nice" solution for me would be using [`.imbue`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#imbue) or [`.for_each`](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#for_each) but with a functor that accepts not only the element's current value but also its location as additional argument; this doesn't seem to be possible currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the armadillo source code, row_col_iterator provides row and column indices of each element. This works like the sparse matrix iterator, but doesn't skip zeros. Adapting your code:

```
mat X(10,10,fill::randu);

mat::const_row_col_iterator it     = X.begin_row_col();
mat::const_row_col_iterator it_end = X.end_row_col();

for (; it != it_end; ++it) {
  cout << "val: " << (*it)    << endl;
  cout << "row: " << it.row() << endl;
  cout << "col: " << it.col() << endl;
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for, thanks for digging into the source code! And it seems to be available since at least 9.900.x – I wonder, why it's not part of the [official docs](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html)...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have already answered your question yourself. I wish armadillo provided us with a `.imbue` method overload that received a functor with as many arguments as the dimension of the armadillo object, but currently it only accepts a functor without arguments. Then the probably simplest option (in my opinion) is using a lambda capturing the necessary information, such as the code below

```cpp
    arma::umat m(3, 3);
    {
        int i = 0;
        m.imbue([&i, num_rows = m.n_rows, num_cols = m.n_cols]() {
            arma::uvec sub = arma::ind2sub(arma::SizeMat{num_rows, num_cols}, i++);
            return 10 * (sub[0] + 1) + sub[1];
        });
    }
```

In this example each element is computed as 10 times its row index plus its column index. I capture `ì` here to be the linear indexing and put it as well as the lambda inside curly brackets to delimit its scope.

I also wish I could write something like `auto [row_idx, col_idx] = arma::ind2sub( ... )`, but unfortunately what `ind2sub` returns does not work with structured binding.

You can also capture `m` by const reference and use `arma::size(m)` as the first argument of `arma::ind2sub`, if you prefer.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about `arma::ind2sub`, which addresses much of the trouble of my suggested workarounds. I guess this answers the question. :) — As you also seem to wish for such functionality: Do you know if this is missing _deliberately_? If not, it might be worthwhile to have a go at an implementation and open an MR ...

Comment: I have no idea if this is deliberately missing or not. If you are interested, you armadillo seems to be hosted in [gitlab](https://gitlab.com/conradsnicta/armadillo-code).